# if a characteristic function is constant on a interval then is constant in all R.

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

I need help with this, please:

If a characteristic function is constant equals 1 on a interval $-r\leq t\leq r$ then is constant in all $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The derivatives of the characteristic function at zero are related to the moments of the random variable. Maybe you can argue from there.

Comment: ... in particular, consider the second derivative.